# Why does coloring by factor fail when using a subset of a data frame?

Tags: r, plot

I have been searching for an answer to this question for a few days, haven't found the answer, and thought that it was time to come here and post a question myself.  I have a data frame that I read in using `read.csv()` with the `as.is=TRUE` flag.

```
x$night <- as.Date(x$night)
x$gsub_version <- as.numeric(x$gsub_version)
x$gsub_version <- x$gsub_version + 1
head(x)
night      filter      mag     mag_err gsub_version
2013-10-08      B 17.67273 0.003226886            1
2013-10-08      B 17.80228 0.003165991            2
```

To save space, I clipped the results.  I want to plot the data with `filter=='V'` and `col=factor(x$gsub_version)`.

```
plot(mag ~ night, data=x[x$filter=="V",], ylim=c(21,17), col=factor(x$gsub_version))
```

Unfortunately this produces this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2OwH.png) with incorrect colors after a certain point.  When I include the extra step to create a dedicated data frame for the `filter` variable, the plot looks correct.

```
y <- x[x$filter=="V",]
plot(mag ~ night, data=y, ylim=c(21,17), col=factor(y$gsub_version))
```

And here is the [new plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ICVu.png) that is produced.  The new plot correctly uses the values of `gsub_version`.  My question is twofold: What makes these two methods different considering that y is comprised of the same subset used to make the first plot, and why is the first method failing?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Seems like perhaps `factor(x$gsub_version)` is not subsetted. Try the first line with `with(x, factor(gsub_version[filter == "V"]))`

Comment: It doesn't work because you are incorrect that `x$gsub_version` is the same as `y$gsub_version`. When you subset the data frame with `data = x[x$filter=="V",]`, that subsetting only applies to the formula. You separately passed an _unfiltered_ vector of colors with `x$gsub_version`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mentioned in the comments. Adding this answer to illustrate how much simpler this sort of thing is using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x) #convert from data.frame to data.table

x[filter == "V", plot(mag ~ night, ylim = c(21, 17), col = factor(gsub_version))]
```

Clean, transparent, and none of the mess of keeping track of which vector is subsetted where -- all of the subsetting is done in the first argument of `[]`.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you!